# Spyder IDE menu text and layout are huge

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, spyder, screen-resolution

I'm not sure what happened, but now when I open Spyder, the menu text and layout size are huge compared to the text in the code editor and interactive window. I've tried adjusting the screen resolution settings, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

- Spyder version: 5.5.0  (conda)
- Python version: 3.11.5 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.15.2
- PyQt5 version: 5.15.7
- Operating System: Windows-10-10.0.22621

[image: Spyder]

[image: Menus]